# How do I use Moneris Payment Gateway?

Tags: payment-gateway

I am creating a website in PHP. My client has an account with [Moneris payment 
gateway](http://www.moneris.com/). How can I use this gateway with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [their API integration page](https://developer.moneris.com/). Unfortunately, you'll have to register to get access to download the documentation.